# Last.FM cannot return more than 500 records when using pylast program

Tags: python, last.fm

I use `pylast` to get information from Last.fm API.

When I use the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pylast

API_KEY = "############################"
API_SECRET = "##############################"

###### In order to perform a write operation you need to authenticate yourself
username = "########"
password_hash = pylast.md5("###########")
network = pylast.LastFMNetwork(api_key = API_KEY, api_secret = API_SECRET, username =         username, password_hash = password_hash)

##          _________INIT__________
COUNTRY = "United Kingdom"

#---------------------- Get Geo Country --------------------
geo_country = network.get_country(COUNTRY)
print "The country we are digging is", geo_country

#----------------------  Get artist --------------------
top_artists_of_country = geo_country.get_top_artists(limit = 1000)
top_artists_of_country_file = open('test_artist_number.txt', 'w+')
print >> top_artists_of_country_file, top_artists_of_country
top_artists_of_country_file.close()
```

I found that I cannot get, for instance, 1000 records when I call

```
 geo_country.get_top_artists(limit = 1000)
```

I just want to know, is this limitation caused by Last.fm's API setings or by `pylast`?

Any help would be great:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [limitation of Last.fm](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&api_key=d0564715b4964a6ade521c22a595064b&limit=1000).

Comment: Thanks, then what can I do if I want to use pylast to get more than 500 queries?

Comment: @MaiTiano Actually I was wrong, `geo.getTopArtists` has a limit of 500 at API level.

Comment: I do not see any limitation in API help page: http://cn.last.fm/api/show?service=297

Comment: It can only mention that :

limit (Optional) : The number of results to fetch per page. Defaults to 50.

Now, I noticed that there is a "per page". Is that means only 500 records included in one page???

If so, how can I get more than one pages's data such that I can get more 500 records...

Please give me some help, I really stuck here for a very long time.

Comment: @MaiTiano Click the link, it has `limit=1000`, but returns only 500 entries. So it can't be a problem of `pylast`. I assume it isn't documented.

Comment: It can only mention that : limit (Optional) : The number of results to fetch per page. Defaults to 50. Now, I noticed that there is a "per page". Is that means only 500 records included in one page??? If so, how can I get more than one pages's data such that I can get more 500 records... Please give me some help, I really stuck here for a very long time. –

Comment: @MaiTiano Everything is documented only in ideal world. In our real world some limitations can be undocumented. It's just that case. You can't get more than 500 artists. Try asking about that at [lastfm forum](http://www.last.fm/group/Last.fm+Web+Services/forum/21604), may be you will get feedback from developers.

Comment: @MaiTiano You can play with the `page` parameter in the [API](http://www.last.fm/api/show?service=297) to get results beyond 500. I didn't work fine for me using `limit=500`, but it did with `limit=250` and `page=3`.

Comment: @jcollado Doesn't work for me, returns only page 2 (251-500). Can you show the exact link?

Comment: @DrTyrsa Uhm, sorry, I checked it again and it looks like when you go beyond 500 you get the last result.

Comment: yes, I double checked , the page number also dose not work for adding more records.  LastFM API seems to only afford no more than 500 items.